# Example of Observable.Throw

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I'm kinda new to Observables so I'm just looking for an example that will set me in the right direction (tutorial maybe?). So here it is - I want to create async `Observable` and thow an `Exception` from it. Here is my example:

```
    protected IObservable<Tuple<DataPart1, DataPart2>> LoadAllDataFunc(string FileName)
    {
        return Observable.Start<Tuple<DataPart1, DataPart2>>(() =>
        {
            ConfigReaderWriter readerWriter = new ConfigReaderWriter();
            try
            {
                readerWriter.UnpackFile(fileName, out DataPart1, out DataPart2);
                return Tuple.Create(DataPart1, DataPart2);
            }
            catch (Exception exp_gen)
            {
                Observable.Throw<Exception>(exp_gen);
                return null;
            }
        });
    }
```

The problem is that I don't think I'm not throwing `Exception` correctly. For example - any Subscriber:

```
    internal IObservable<DataPart2> GetProject()
    {
        if (this.GlobalDataPart2 != null)
            return Observable.Return(GlobalDataPart2);

        IObservable<Project> receivedData = null;

        var loadAll = LoadAllDataFunc(this.GlobalFileName).Subscribe(
                data => { receivedData = Observable.Return(data.Item1); },
                (ex) => { Observable.Throw<Exception>(ex); }
            );

        return receivedData;
    }
```

will not receive `Exception` from `LoadAllDataFunc` ? Even **if** exception occurred the Subscriber will receive `null`.

So - what is correct way to throw exception from Observable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to make it crystal clear what Observable.Throw does: it returns an observable sequence (of the specified element type) whose sole role it is to tell all of its observers about an exception by calling their OnError method:

```
var err = Observable.Throw<int>(new Exception("Oops!"));
err.Subscribe(_ => {}, ex => { Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); }, () => {});
err.Subscribe(_ => {}, ex => { Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); }, () => {});
```

The code above will print Oops! twice.

As Gideon mentioned, operators like Start will propagate user exceptions to the OnError channel. If you use Observable.Create though, talk to the observer directly about the error case:

```
var res = Observable.Create<int>(observer =>
{
    return scheduler.Schedule(() =>
    {
        var res = default(int);

        try
        {
            res = ComputationThatMayFail();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            observer.OnError(ex);
            return;
        }

        observer.OnNext(res);
        observer.OnCompleted();
    });
});
```

In fact, the code shown above is pretty close to what Start does anyway. (The one difference has to do with the use of an AsyncSubject to cache the operation's result.)

Comment: Bar De Smet answered my question. Wow ! Thanks man ! Love your work on Observable !

Answer (score 0):

When using `Observable.Start`, the best way will be to simply not catch the exception.  `Observable.Throw` and `Observable.Return` simply create observable sequences; they do not do anything special from inside methods returning `IObservable`, like you seem to expect.  This is why you are not getting the `OnError` call from your top piece of code.  The call to Observable.Throw creates an observable, does nothing with it, and return a null value from the function, which is then sent to the observer's `OnNext`.

Your second piece of code seems to have related issues.  Again, the call to Throw will do nothing.  The OnNext action of that subscriber is also probably not what you want.  In general, you will be returning null from that function as the first result from `LoadAllDataFunc` will probably not have come by the time `GetProject` returns (Subscribe does not generally block.)  What I would guess you want to do there is to use `Select` instead.

```
return LoadAllDataFunc(this.GlobalFileName)
       .Select(data => data.Item1); //should this be Item2?
```